# highcharts tooltip shows scroll bar

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

My highcharts chart tooltip shows an blank scrollbar. This also applies to highstock chart. This issue only occurs on firefox.

I have applied this style in my css file. But it works fine in chrome.

```
.highcharts-tooltip span {
max-height:250px !important;
overflow-y: scroll !important;
 }
```

[image]
How can I solve this?

Comment: In CSS you enable scrolling by overflow-y, so is printed correcly. What is a reson of setting these styles and requirement to not print that?

Answer (score 0):

use auto instead of scroll

overflow-y: auto;